# How do I show the built-in heading styles in Word 2007's Quick Styles Gallery?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, styles

I've inherited a 200+ page Word 2007 document that uses lots of individually-formatted paragraphs rather than paragraph styles. I want to generate a table of contents, but before I can do that, I need to reformat the document to use proper heading styles.

However, the Quick Style Gallery is full of junk and none of the styles there are the built-in ones (Heading 1, Heading 2, etc). I've removed lots of the junk styles from the gallery (by right-clicking on them in the gallery) and even applied a few standard heading styles using their keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+Alt+1, etc), but how do I get these built-in styles to appear in the Quick Style Gallery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. :)

First, you need to bring up the Manage Styles dialog...

You can get to this via the Styles panel, which itself is accessed via the little dialog launcher at the bottom-right of the Styles ribbon section. Once the Styles panel is visible, click the Manage Styles button at the bottom of it (it looks like a little pencil editing the usual "AA" icon):

[image: How to get to the Manage Styles dialog]

Next, you need to edit the Hide-Until-Used property of each of the styles you want to show. On the Recommend tab, find the built-in styles you're after, highlight them, and click the Show button:

[image: Showing the built-in styles]

For me, that was enough to show the styles I wanted in the Quick Styles Gallery.

However, if you're trying to show a built-in style that doesn't normally appear in the gallery, you'll need to go to the Edit tab, select the style, and click Modify. The Modify Style dialog will appear and, in that, you need to select the Add To Quick Style List option.

Job done. :)

Comment: To get rid of all of the "+ styles" stop showing formatting in your styles pane.